# Забыла, как годы до н. э. переводить в века, поможете?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов

Википедия:

> Гай Ци́льний Мецена́т (лат. Gāius Cilnius Maecēnās, около 70 до н. э.
>   — 8 до н. э.) — древнеримский государственный деятель и покровитель
>   искусств.

В моём тексте:

> ...Это место трапез у источника прославленного государственного
>   деятеля и покровителя искусств I века, чьё имя стало нарицательным.

Ну не получается у меня I век... если только ДО НОВОЙ ЭРЫ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Родился Гай Цильний Меценат между 74–64 годами до нашей эры (по одной из версий - 13 апреля 70 года до н.э.). Умер в октябре 8 года до нашей эры (предположительно).
Время жизни, таким образом, полностью "вписывается" в первый век до н.э.

Хочу обратить ваше внимание на некоторую двусмысленность в предложении (как ***мне*** кажется): *источник прославленного государственного деятеля*.
Это был его *собственный* источник? Или это его любимое место для приема пищи (у источника)?

**Дополнение**

Дело в том, что многие статьи в Википедии написаны БЕЗ указания **г., год** или **годы**:

**Марк Ту́ллий Цицеро́н** (лат. Marcus Tullius Cicerō; 3 января 106 до н. э., Арпинум — 7 декабря 43 до н. э., Формия);
**Архиме́д** (Ἀρχιμήδης; 287 до н. э. — 212 до н. э.);
**Марк Авре́лий Антони́н** (лат. Marcus Aurelius Antoninus; 26 апреля 121, Рим — 17 марта 180, Виндобона).

Answer (score 2):

Ну конечно, I век до н. э. если он умер в 8 году до н.э. Просто опечатка, видимо.